# DAX - Apply SUM on SUMMARIZE

Tags: sql, service, dax, analysis

Following is my DAX:

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZE (
    DimProducts,
    DimProducts[Id],
    DimProducts[Price],

    "Quantity", 
    SUMX (
    FILTER( 'FactSales','DimProducts'[Id] = 'FactSales'[ProductId]),
    FactSales[Quantity]),

    "QuantityXInitialTicket",
    SUMX (
    FILTER( 'FactSales','DimProducts'[Id] = 'FactSales'[ProductId]),
    FactSales[Quantity] * DimProducts[Price])
)
```

It is giving following results:
[View Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48GZV.jpg)

Now, I need to get the SUM of Column QuantityXInitialTicket.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the total sum of QuantityXInitialTicket, why don't you skip SUMMERIZE and just use the following:

```
SUMX (
    FILTER( 'FactSales','DimProducts'[Id] = 'FactSales'[ProductId]), 
    FactSales[Quantity] * DimProducts[Price]
)
```

It calculates the expression regardless of your "group by" summerization on DimProduct[Id] and DimProduct[Price], which equals to the sum of QuantityXInitialTicket.

If you wish to keep the summerized table and still perform the summation, use the following:

```
VAR SummerizeTable = SUMMERIZE(...)
EVALUATE SUM(SummerizeTable[QuantityXInitialTicket])
```

Hope that helps.